# How to avoid passing a reference to the container or using CommonServiceLocator for an EntityFactory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, entity, factory

My Entity class has a dependency on a Repository.

```
public class User
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public User(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

And I have an EntityFactory class used by the Repository to create entities.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly EntityFactory _entityFactory;

    public UserRepository(EntityFactory entityFactory)
    {
        _entityFactory = entityFactory;
    }

    ...
}

// EntityFactory #1 with no references or dependencies to DI frameworks or CommonServiceLocator
public class EntityFactory
{
    public User InstantiateUser()
    {
        return new User(); // Requires IUserRepository parameter
    }
}

// EntityFactory #2 with reference to Ninject
using Ninject;

public class EntityFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public EntityFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public User InstantiateUser(IKernel kernel)
    {
        return new User(_kernel.Get<IUserRepository>());
    }
}

// EntityFactory #3 with reference to CommonServiceLocator
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

public class EntityFactory
{
    public User InstantiateUser()
    {
        return new User(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUserRepository>());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the EntityFactory having a reference to the container or using the CommonServiceLocator? (Context Agnostic)

Or am I just designing my classes wrong and the User class should not have a dependency on any Repositories?

**Edit:** Here is the code using the method from David:

```
// Ninject binding
Bind<Func<User>>().ToMethod(cxt => () => new User(cxt.Kernel.Get<IUserRepository>()));

// EntityFactory class
private readonly Func<User> _userFactory;
public EntityFactory(Func<User> userFactory)
{
    _userFactory = userFactory;
}
public User InstantiateUser()
{
    return userFactory.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<User>()` or `_kernel.Get<User>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DI framework should provide you with a method of creating factories:

```
public class EntityFactory
{
    public EntityFactory(Func<User> userFactory) { /* ... */ }

    public User InstantiateUser()
    {
        return userFactory.Invoke();
    }
}
```

When the `EntityFactory` is created it'll receive a proper `User` factory which can then be used to create properly resolved users without any reference to the IoC.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what I am looking for. Although I'm still not sure about having several Func<Entity> factory fields in my EntityFactory. It seems like modifying the code too much to make it fit the DI style. How would it work with Unit Testing?

Comment: @Rudy: if your EntityFactory only invokes factory methods, it might make sense to dispense with it all-together. Another would be to create a small FactoryByTypeCache who would encapsulate/cache/memoize the factory creation. In unit-testing, you can override the factory delegates in your container and/or replace the EntityFactory totally. (See also the Repository pattern)

Answer (score 0):

**What's wrong with option 2 or 3? If you are using IoC or a service locator, you will need to have a reference to it somewhere.**

I have a global reference to the IoC container and use that to resolve the interfaces all over the place. This looks a lot like the service locator, but then instead using the IoC container.

I don't believe there is a way around this.

Comment: Options 2 or 3 make it very hard to switch out the IoC, or use two different configurations in the same appdomain, because they sprinkle static references all over the place. The proper usage scenario should require references to the IoC only when registering components and for resolving the "application" in the orchestrator.

Comment: I believe option 2 actually does implement this, requiring the IoC container to be passed when instantiating the EntityFractory. I implemented IoC by having a static class wrapper which has the option to switch IoC containers based on some `ThreadStatic` reference (the context of the current request). However, it is also possible to simply create a second `AppDomain` if the IoC container is specific to e.g. a module or plugin.